# Software to restore data from a fillable PDF

Tags: pdf, data-recovery

I recently restored PDF files from a corrupted USB drive using Disk Drill on Mac OS X. However, none of the filled-in field data came along for the ride. When I view the restored files, all the fields are blank.

Does anyone have a recommendation for what I might use to restore the missing data? Thanks!